# How to start youtube-dl autonumber from a different number than 1?

Tags: youtube-dl, autonumber

I was downloading a playlist from youtube using youtube-dl. I used autonumbering feature to number the videos which could be achieved by formatting the name of output file as follows -o "%(autonumber)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s". The download failed in between. Now I wish to start the autonumber from the video next to failed video and not 1. But autonumber resets itself to 1 everytime. How can I set it to a different number greater than 1 ?

Comment: am afraid that the one option is to starting download in another folder and then shift numbers manually or via some script

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For playlists you should use `playlist_index` instead: `-o '%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s'`

Comment: Also adding --continue solves this problem. Youtube-dl will resume from where it failed.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `%(playlist_index)s`, you should use `youtube-dl --autonumber-start 5 $URL -o "%(autonumber)s_stuff"`
It will start `%(autonumber)s` at 5 in this case.